# Is there any way to simulate belt transsmition with non-circular cog?

Tags: simulation, power-transmission, transmission, autodesk-inventor

I want to do a simulation of a transmission with toothed belt and elliptical gear. I've tried in Autodesk inventor by modeling wheels separately and then adding a belt with the "synchronous belt tool" but the software doesn't recognize elliptical cog as a cog. I'm thinking about doing an accurate model of the belt, but is there some kind of constraint/link I can apply in the assembly process that would make the belt move realistically when I simulate the rotation of the cogs?

I'd really like to see your point of view.

[image: similar to this] 
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by “simulation”? Just visually? To find out forces?

Comment: I want to see the forces or tension in the belt because the second condition for proper gear operation, in this setup (with elliptical gear), is proper circulation of its movement. This circulation is provided only by toothed belts, that have a very small increase in their permanent deformations during operation, so the tension can't be too high. At the same time, the preload of the belt should be correct to prevent slipping/skipping the teeth.